# glfw resizing causing image scaling

Tags: opengl, graphics, glfw, window-management

I have a quad rendered that extends from the top left of the window to with width of the window that is also 64 pixels high. When I resize the window, from its initial size, the quad and text scales proportionately bigger or smaller in the same say Photoshop can scale a image. What I'm seeking on a basic level is that regardless of how I resize the window, everything drawn remains the same. From the below image, the right side is the initial size and the left side is what happens when I drag the window to be a smaller size. The red bar and text scales with it. This is how Im handling my resizing:

```
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(pWindow, WindowSizeCallback); // initialized after context

void WindowSizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glfwSetWindowSize(window, width, height);    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `glViewport(0, 0, width, height);` when your framebuffer size changes. Do note that `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback` gives you screen coordinates, so perhaps instead of sticking the `glViewport` call inside `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback`, you want to set it from `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback`.